# How to test custom `Document` in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I have a custom `Document` which is copied from the [document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document):

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

I tried to write test for it with the following below:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyDocument from '../_document.page';

describe('<MyDocument />', () => {
  it('should render without errors', async () => {
    const documentProps = {} as any;

    render(<MyDocument {...documentProps} />);
  });
});
```

But I get an error:

```sh
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'inAmpMode' of '(0 , _react).useContext(...)' as it is null.

       6 |     const documentProps = {} as any;
       7 |
    >  8 |     render(<MyDocument {...documentProps} />);
         |     ^
       9 |   });
      10 | });
```

What is the recommended way to test the custom document or how do I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: does your component require the property `inAmpMode` ? You need to pass the required props to the component.

Comment: No, not using inAmpMode. How do I pass the required props if the component doesn't use inAmpMode?

Comment: The error seems to occur in MyDocument, which you haven't shown. To me it looks like inAmpMode is missing. Pass the props required by the component e.g.: `render(<MyDocument { someProp1: value1, ... } />)`

Comment: @kca yeah I suspect the same but not sure what to pass, this component is rendered by Next itself, so only Next would know what to pass, I'm not sure what though.

Comment: oh, sorry, obviously I didn't read you question carefully. You are right, interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error - ended up mocking next/document, and returning a mockImplementation of Html.

```
jest.mock('next/document', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('next/document'),
  Html: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    render() {
      return React.createElement('html', { 'data-testid': 'html' });
    }
  }))
}));
```